# How to add the AM or PM to time date format in ANT task?

Tags: ant

I have a date and time stamp that I would like to add the AM or PM value to. I haven't found the way to do this. Here is my code:

```
<target name="updateDate">

    <propertyset id="tdate"></propertyset>

    <tstamp>
        <format property="tdate" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"/>
    </tstamp>

    <echo>Updating build date to: ${tdate}</echo>

    <replaceregexp byline="true">
        <regexp pattern="BUILD_DATE:String\s+=\s+(['|&quot;])([a-zA-Z0-9-:\s]+)(['|&quot;])"/>
        <substitution expression="BUILD_DATE:String = \1${tdate}\3"/>
        <fileset dir="project/src/model">
            <include name="ProjectModel.as"/>
        </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>

</target>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ```
> a     Am/pm marker    Text    PM
> ```

So

```
<format property="tdate" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a"/>
```

Note that this is redundant with `HH`, since `HH` prints the hour from 00 to 23. Use `hh` to get the hour from 01 to 12.